# a href background-color change based on field value

Tags: php, html, css

I have a field called 'availability' that can be changed between 'Available' and 'UNavailable' for users to choose.  If the user is available, I want to have a background of a green color; red is for UNavailable users.

```
$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'");
                        $sql->execute();
                        while($row = $sql->fetch()){
                    ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php if ($availability = 'UNavailable') { ?>
                      <a style="margin:10px;background-color:#FF2828;color:#fff;border-radius:25px;padding:10px;" href="avail/index.php" class="true_home"><?php echo $row['availability']; ?></a></td>
                      <?php
                    } else if ($availability = 'Available') { ?>
                        <a style="margin:10px;background-color:#008000;border-radius:25px;padding:10px;" href="avail/index.php" class="true_home"><?php echo $row['availability']; ?></a></td>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Whichever availability status I list first, the color always chooses that one.  It ignores the else.  I've used else if and just else to see if any changes would occur to allow the value to dictate the background color.  Neither have worked.

As always, I truly value everyone's input.

Comment: You have to use JS for it. PHP is not dynamically change the info

Comment: Thanks @gguney, I will give JS a try.

Comment: Where is your availability variable even defined?

Comment: Availability is a field in my mysql table.  There is another form where the user selects if he/she is available or unavailable for work.  That option is then saved in the users table.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

```
<style>
.Available {
    background-color:#008000;
}
.UNavailable {
    background-color:#FF2828;
}
</style>
<?php
$sql = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '" . 
$_SESSION['username'] . "'");
$sql->execute();
while ($row = $sql->fetch())
{ ?>
<tr>
    <td>
    <a style="margin:10px;border-radius:25px;padding:10px;" href="avail/index.php" class="true_home <?php echo $availability ?>"><?php echo $row['availability']; ?></a>
    </td>
</tr><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I appreciate that @RagupathiS, but it did not work.  You defined the classes in the style, but did not declare them in the html.  After I added a class for each with an if/else statement, it is still doing the same thing and only displaying the first color it reads.